# How to make a list of objects which are checked in GWT?

Tags: java, checkbox, gwt, gxt

I am developing an GWT app where I am using check-boxes. I have list of GwtRoles which are in checkboxes, but I don't know how to get those GwtRoles that are checked. This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void createBody() {

    for (GwtRole gwtRole : roleList) {
                checkBox = new CheckBox();
                checkBox.setBoxLabel(gwtRole.getName());
                for (GwtAccessRole gwtAccessRole : lista) {
                    if (gwtRole.getId().equals(gwtAccessRole.getRoleId())) {
                        checkBox.setValue(true);
                    }
```

RoleList is list of GwtRoles that are in checkboxes. This lista is a list of items that should be pre-checked when user opens form. I am not really familiar with check-boxes in GWT. 
I have used CheckBox list and there I had method getChecked() which returns list of all checked GwtRoles, but here with this check-boxes I don't have that option.
In this method I should make a list of GwtRoles which are checked:

```
 @Override
    public void submit() {

        List<GwtAccessRoleCreator> listCreator = new ArrayList<GwtAccessRoleCreator>();

        for (GwtRole role : list) {
            GwtAccessRoleCreator gwtAccessRoleCreator = new GwtAccessRoleCreator();

            gwtAccessRoleCreator.setScopeId(currentSession.getSelectedAccount().getId());

            gwtAccessRoleCreator.setAccessInfoId(accessInfoId);

            gwtAccessRoleCreator.setRoleId(role.getId());
            listCreator.add(gwtAccessRoleCreator);
        }
        GWT_ACCESS_ROLE_SERVICE.createCheck(xsrfToken, currentSession.getSelectedAccount().getId(), userId, listCreator, new AsyncCallback<GwtAccessRole>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GwtAccessRole arg0) {
                exitStatus = true;
                exitMessage = MSGS.dialogAddConfirmation();
                hide();
            }
```

Could someone helps me how to set a list of GwtRoles which are checked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of your `CheckBox`s in a `Map` and then just return the `GwtRole`s for which the checkbox is checked.

```
private Map<GwtRole, CheckBox> mapping = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void createBody() {
    for (GwtRole gwtRole : roleList) {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        mapping.put(gwtRole, checkBox);
        // Your other code here.
    }
}

// Java 8
public List<GwtRole> getChecked()
{
    return mapping.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().getValue())
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

// Pre-Java 8
public List<GwtRole> getChecked()
{
    List<GwtRole> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Map.Entry<GwtRole, CheckBox> e : map.entrySet())
    {
        if(e.getValue().getValue())
            result.add(e.getKey());
    }

    return result;
}
```